# SKTexture size is drastically wrong

Tags: sprite-kit, dimension, sktexture

When I make a simple texture for a sprite node and put it on scene, it is drastically bigger then the image actually is. Image is of size 25x58. I don't know the actual size on the screen, but looks like 200x200 (probably even more than that!) approximately. I can't have it this big. What can be the cause for this? Thanks guys!

Comment: You should show the relevant code... Also, check for typos(check the texture name), clear simulator's content and settings and delete derived data. Delete .atlas folders if you use them , clean project (product -> clean) and re-add them.

Comment: also check your scaleMode,  if you are using the defaults,  this means your scene space is 600x600.  so you are throwing a 25x58 image into a 600x600 scene, which will get doubled or tripled in size with the retina mode, followed by the scaling of your device (If Iphone 6+, it could scale to about 3x more if your view is registering as 1242x2208 instead of the normal 414x736)

Comment: Hay thanks, Knight, this is probably the cause, since I ruled some other things out.